# How to make data accessible to a React Component when data exists outside of states scope

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, scope, webvr

. .

I am currently using React VR for a school project, but incorporating vanilla javascript into the index.html to create a static HTML UI. In this case I am using an HTML5 form to post data to my back end, yet still, I would like to optimistically render the data using a React component rather than have to retrieve the data from the server.

My data is created in the HTML element, and it needs to make its way into a React Component.

I don't think refs will work, as the research I have done shows that they are for accessing data which is being generated by a React component, and in my case, I am looking for the data to flow from the HTML to the React Component.

```
    ~ JAVASCRIPT & HTML ~

     //Accepts the Input
        <form id='idea-form'>
          <input type="text" id="hiddenInput" maxlength=95 autocomplete=off>                
        </form>


          // Initialize the React VR application.
        ReactVR.init(
         '../index.vr.bundle?platform=vr&dev=true',
          document.body
        );
```

I've included my component here, minus imports and exports.

The component maps an array of strings, converts them to JSX, then renders  components with the array elements as the text props for the component.

In my case,

```
//========== IdeaContainer Component ==========
class IdeaContainer extends Component {

  //---------- Other Methods ----------
  mapIdeasContentToJSX(ideasObjArr) {
    newIdeas = [...ideasObjArr]enter code here
    ideasJSX = newIdeas.map((idea) => {return (<IdeaText
      text={idea.content}
      y={Math.random() * 30}
      z={Math.random() * -80}
    />)})
    return ideasJSX
  }

  //---------- Lifecycle Methods ----------
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.preLoadIdeas()
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <View>
        {this.mapIdeasContentToJSX(this.props.ideaList)}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the code which lives in the index.html, which exists outside the scope of my React components, meaning I cannot pass it as props or set it to state, as far as I know.

The element with id of 'container' is where the data is being entered, which then needs to make its way to the React Component

```
<div>
  <div id='logoDIV'class="relative" >
  <img id='logoIMG' src='./logo.png' draggable="false">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container" style='position: fixed; z-index: 2; bottom: 1%; right: 22%;'>
    <div id="input"></div>
      <form id='idea-form'>
        <input type="text" id="hiddenInput" maxlength=95 autocomplete=off>
      </form>
</div>
      <canvas id="cloudCover"></canvas>
<!-- When you're ready to deploy your app, update this line to point to your compiled client.bundle.js -->
<script src="./client.bundle?platform=vr"></script>
<script src="./input.js"></script>
<script src='./clouds.js'></script>
<script>
  ReactVR.init(
    // When you're ready to deploy your app, update this line to point to
    // your compiled index.bundle.js
    '../index.vr.bundle?platform=vr&dev=true',
    document.body
  );
</script>
<script>
  let x = document.body.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(8) > div > a:nth-child(2)')
  x.style.bottom = '100px'
</script>
```

Comment: Post your entire react component

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for refs.

```
<input 
   type="text" 
   id="hiddenInput" 
   maxlength=95 
   autocomplete=off
   ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
```

Then you can access the input value like this:

```
this.textInput.value
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html